# I am not able to open my application using FireFox C# selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, windows-authentication

I want to test my unit cases using firefox. I am using C# selenium webdriver. My application uses windows authentication. The code is

```
FirefoxOptions d= new FirefoxOptions();
```

*In URL i am passing username and password*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amna - I am looking for a better way to handle Windows Authentication but here is something that will work.

Add NuGet package AutoIT

Then add this to your login:

```
bool ele1 = AutoItX.WinExists("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]")== 1;

if (ele1)
{
AutoItX.WinActivate("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]"); 
AutoItX.Send("Username");
AutoItX.Send("{TAB}");
AutoItX.Send("Password");
AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```

Alert Login was Deprecated as was user/pass in the url string. AutoIT is the only thing that has worked but it is not thread safe so you have to run single thread.

Comment: It is working fine for passing username and password but as soon as username and pw is enetered , the browser gets closed, making my testcase failed. How can I run my test case successfully that firefox does not get closed.

Comment: If this issue is resolved, I would start a new thread and detail the issues.

Comment: okay. This issue as mentioned in the question is resolved. but not the one mentioned in the comment.